# Insert data in collection name contain in dot notation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to insert document in collection name contain dot notation?

For Ex:
 collection: blog and blog. post
Insert: db.blog.insert("document");
how to insert in 2nd collection?

Comment: That would be an update, then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
db.blog.post.insert({ /* document */ });
```

?

Keep in mind that such a notation **doesn't have any different semantics for mongodb**, the collection name `blog.post` doesn't mean the collection is in any way related to the `blog` collection, i.e. it doesn't make a difference whether you name your collection `blog.post` or `blog_post` or simply `posts`.

This notation is, however, used by MongoDB for its GridFS implementation which by default writes to `db.fs.files` and `db.fs.chunks`.